# Invalid domain name Azure Active directory issue and Migration to Microsoft Graph C# application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to run below code to get the user details as response from Azure Active Directory  :

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AADConsole2
{
    class Program
    {

        private const string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
        private const string resource= "https://graph.windows.net";
        private const string GraphServiceObjectId = "XXX";
        private const string TenantId = "XXXXX";
        private const string tenant = "company.onmicrosoft.com";
        private const string ClientId = "XXXX";
        private static string appKey= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        static string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

        private static HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        private static AuthenticationContext context = null;
        private static ClientCredential credential = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            credential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, appKey);
            Task<string> token = GetToken();
            token.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(token.Result);
            Task<string> users = GetUsers(token.Result);
            users.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(users.Result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetUsers(string result) {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            string users = null;
            string queryString = "test";
```

var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/{your_tenant_name}.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6";

```
            httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result);
            var getResult = await httpclient.GetAsync(uri);

            if(getResult.Content != null)
            {
                users = await getResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
            return users;

        }


        private static async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            string token = null;
            result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);
            token = result.AccessToken;
            return token;



        }
    }
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
uMCJ9.FdttazjoKYZWP_SmC5B7Nd3kOF-jRs62WLKYovDA8qMvybLTw8yIUoihp7I00ctJGJHDoEbhbIi0XHp9Ujdq0bNPlG-L5SoE9IFSoxX3ZQOZwSf90b_nDapbHJ8KCHZUnCBOwVnYiTXtpIQfrDVqqENarrIGa_uUbiriomYiB8gVkKWe6PB-I4lsYPEmMNnnpdvIf1eV_CsTmvUA54Ch1Zdip9mxrzRqrUqsx6vUTo0riCmiCxRg7mH2DuMaEPTZuQAMwhrQM_EwNsgx1yX1VsCKkL1Gu7CV_dqW5xxYlE7NEQmorT8W6aySbiBzsUWisJNnaR8RqZzeAUlSVMKBiw
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Invalid domain name in the request url."},"requestId":"01ab745b-8a3f-48cc-9542-0c6abcae8950","date":"2020-02-17T22:41:28"}}
r
```

Also ,help me in getting  tenant name ( it's a name or alphanumeric id ?) ,currently i am just using below tenant name.
private const string tenant = "company.onmicrosoft.com";

I only want to use Microsoft Graph API in this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i also want to know the whether this code is using Microsoft Graph or
>   Azure AD.

This code is using Azure AD Graph API. It works fine if the request uri is correct.You should use your tenant name, not `company.onmicrosoft.com`, and you must specify the api-version. So the request uri should be

```
var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/{your_tenant_name}.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6";
```

If the tenant name is wrong, you will encounter Invalid domain name error.

> I am not sure whether to use https://graph.microsoft.com or
>   https://graph.windows.net.

You can use either one. But the official document **strongly recommend that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) resources**.

If you want to use Microsoft Graph API, just change the value of resource and request api url. The resource will be `https://graph.microsoft.com`. The request api url will be `var uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users";`.

**Note:** Remember to grant your application the correct permissions in Azure portal and grant admin consent.

[image]

Comment: It is a strong recommendation to use MS Graph API if it provides what you need.

Comment: @Tony Ju. Thanks a lot , your recommended changes work. i changed my code to         private const string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
and             var uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users";
So ,now i can say its a Microsoft Graph API .